# PyQt: Why does a QButtonGroup in a method need 'self.' prefix to signal buttonClicked?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5

I created a QMainWindow GUI that uses a toolbar of radio buttons to select the main display (i.e. which widget of a QStackedWidget is displayed). I finally got a QButtonGroup's signal to be detected, but I don't fully understand why my fix worked.

Here is a minimal working example; the focus is the `modelButtonGroup` method.

```
class myGui(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):

        super(myGui, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupCentral()
        self.setupButtonToolBar()

    def setupCentral(self):

        self.stackedWidget = QStackedWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.stackedWidget)

        windowA = QWidget()
        windowALayout = QGridLayout()
        windowALayout.addWidget(QLabel('Window A'))

        windowB = QWidget()
        windowBLayout = QGridLayout()
        windowBLayout.addWidget(QLabel('Window B'))

        windowA.setLayout(windowALayout)
        windowB.setLayout(windowBLayout)

        self.stackedWidget.addWidget(windowA)
        self.stackedWidget.addWidget(windowB)
        self.stackedWidget.setCurrentIndex(0)

    def setupButtonToolBar(self):

        buttonBar = QToolBar()
        buttonBar.addWidget(self.modelButtonGroup())
        self.addToolBar(buttonBar)

    def modelButtonGroup(self):

        modelsWidget = QWidget()
        modelsLayout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.ButtonGroup = QButtonGroup()

        windowA_Button = QRadioButton('Window A')
        windowA_Button.setChecked(True)
        self.ButtonGroup.addButton(windowA_Button, 0)

        windowB_Button = QRadioButton('Window B')
        self.ButtonGroup.addButton(windowB_Button, 1)

        self.ButtonGroup.buttonClicked[int].connect(self.switchdisplay)

        modelsLayout.addWidget(windowA_Button)
        modelsLayout.addWidget(windowB_Button)
        modelsWidget.setLayout(modelsLayout)

        return modelsWidget

    def switchdisplay(self, id):
        print('button %d has been pressed' % id)
        self.stackedWidget.setCurrentIndex(id)
```

My understanding is that, if a name in one method is only referenced within that method, and isn't referred to elsewhere in the class, then `self.` is not needed as a prefix. However, if `ButtonGroup` is used instead of `self.ButtonGroup`, its `.buttonClicked` signal doesn't get processed by `switchdisplay`.

While writing this question, I *think* I determined why this is, but would appreciate confirmation. `modelButtonGroup` returns only the widget of buttons, and is only called when setting up the GUI. The `ButtonGroup`is not passed out of the function, and is garbage collected. The 'self.' prefix is required for it to 'live on', even if it's not directly referred to by name.

Am I understanding this correctly?

Comment: `ButtonGroup` must be a member of the class, if you do not want to use `self.ButtonGroup`, you can use `ButtonGroup = QButtonGroup(self)`

Comment: This is a general Python feature/effect, isn't it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I see that you already figured it out yourself:

> The `ButtonGroup` is not passed out of the function, and is garbage collected. The 'self.' prefix is required for it to 'live on', even if it's not directly referred to by name.
>
> Am I understanding this correctly?

Yes.  That is exactly what is happening here. If you don't retain a reference to `ButtonGroup`, then it is deleted as soon as it goes out of scope (at the function exit).  It will never emit any signals.

I think @eyllanesc's answer might work, too.  In that case, the reference to the `ButtonGroup` object would be retained implicitly, as a child within the `parent` class.

FWIW, I typically encounter bugs like this when I'm dealing with `QMenu` objects.

Answer (score 3):

`ButtonGroup` must be a member of the class, if you do not want to use `self.ButtonGroup`, you can use `ButtonGroup = QButtonGroup(self)`